# FFmpeg upgrade to version 6, format duration big increase

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I am using this command to extract metadata from a video:

```
ffprobe -v error -print_format json -show_format -show_streams too-many-packets.mp4
```

with ffmpeg v5.1.4 I get normal format duration: 6.452311 But when using v6.1.1 The Format duration is: 35393.442471 (Audio stream and video stream duration are normal in both versions).

Is there any reason for the duration huge increase from 6.45 seconds to
35393 seconds?

Link to video and both outputs:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BT6NMqZ2pSd-shbu-hok-2-Gaihn0Av2?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Execute: `ffprobe -v error -print_format json -show_packets too-many-packets.mp4 > 1.txt`, and check the `pts_time` of the last packets. The `pts_time` of the last packet is `35393.416576`, the duration is `0.026122`, the total duration is the sum: `35393.442`. The packets with the large pts_time are marked with flag `"flags": "K_"`. I think it means they should be ignored. It's difficult to say if it's a bug in FFmpeg 6.1.1. I don't know if "Format duration" suppose to include the packets with `"flags": "K_"`. or not.